# Copy file to specified path

Tags: shell

i write a shell script 
fuction：

in a dirctory find some files I need, then copy to specified path

```
ls | grep FILENAME | sed 's/^/cp / | sed 's/$/ PATH/' | sh -x
```

How to make it more simple?

Comment: Why does `cp FILENAME PATH` not work?

Answer (score 1):

You can try `cp *FILENAME* PATH`